# Why does this not contradict the Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=2−|4x−2|$. Show that there is no value of c such that $f(3)−f(0)=f'(c)(3−0)$. So Why does this not contradict the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: You can apply MVT to differentiable functions.

Comment: Can you find a point where your function is **not** differentiable?

Answer (score 3):

Note that prerequisite of Mean Value Thm:

If a function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$, **and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$**.

However, for your function: $f(x)=2-|4x-2|$ is continuous but **NOT differentiable** at point $(\dfrac{1}{2},2)$. So we **CANNOT** apply Mean Value Thm. It doesn't contradict to the theorem.